# Why is class with non-const copy constructor not treated as copy constructible?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Given

```
struct Foo 
{
    Foo(Foo&) {} 
};
```

`std::is_copy_constructible<Foo>::value` is `false`

Foo has valid copy-constructor: From draft n4659:

```
15.8.1 Copy/move constructors [class.copy.ctor]
1
A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X& , const X& ,
volatile X& or const volatile X& , and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters
have default arguments (11.3.6). [Example: X::X(const X&) and X::X(X&,int=1) are copy constructors.
```

but `is_copy_constructible` tests `is_constructible_v<T, const T&>` (**const**) according to the standard.

Why is class with non-const copy constructor not  treated as copy constructible?

Comment: From [is_copy_constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible), it is equivalent to `std::is_constructible<T, const T&>::value`, you may still use `std::is_constructible<T, T&>::value`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Actually, I can't. It is used internally in library calls like `emplace_back` to `std::vector` ...

Comment: @relaxxx It is used internally to give nice error messages, even if it weren't there your code couldn't possibly compile: Since you declared a copy-constructor, move operations are no longer generated implicitly. `emplace_back` however, will sometimes need to grow the vector and thus tries to move elements into the new buffer. The old elements are hence converted to xvalues with `std::move` (or something similar), but these can't bind to the `Foo&` in your copy constructor when trying to construct the element in the new buffer.

Comment: You either need to add a move constructor that takes a `Foo&&` or an additional copy constructor that takes a `Foo const&` or change the existing copy constructor to take a `Foo const&` (which you should probably do regardless of whether you add a move constructor or not). Note that having a copy constructor that actually modifies the other `Foo` can lead to surprising behavior, as the compiler is allowed to elide copies under certain conditions (and guaranteed to do so in C++17)

Comment: @Corristo Nice comment. `std::is_copy_constructible` as in `std::is_copy_constructible_with_good_constructor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is indeed a valid copy constructor, the `is_copy_constructible` type-trait is defined to give the same result as `is_constructible_v<T, const T&>`, because it is intended to correspond to the `CopyConstructible` concept that is also defined by the standard.

In [[utility.arg.requirements]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/utility.arg.requirements#1) it says

> The template definitions in the C++ standard library refer to various named requirements whose details are set out in Tables 20–27. In these tables, `T` is an object or reference type to be supplied by a C++ program instantiating a template;[...] and v is an lvalue of type (**possibly const**) T or an rvalue of type const T.

The CopyConstructible concept is defined in [Table 24](http://eel.is/c++draft/utility.arg.requirements#tab:copyconstructible) as

> Table 24 — CopyConstructible requirements (in addition to MoveConstructible)
>   Expression        Post-condition 
>   T u = v;              the value of v is unchanged and is equivalent to u 
>   T(v)                    the value of v is unchanged and is equivalent to T(v)

Therefore, since your object is not constructible from a `const Foo` lvalue, which is one of the requirements of `CopyConstructible`, it is not regarded as such.