# copy constructor const error while using with map

Tags: c++

The following program works without error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class userContext {
public:
    int id;
    int value1;
    int value2;
    userContext():id(-1),value1(-1),value2(-1){}
    userContext(userContext &context) {
        this->id = context.id;
        this->value1 = context.value1;
        this->value2 = context.value2;
    }
};
int main() {
    userContext a;
    a.id = 1;
    a.value1 = 2;
    a.value2 = 3;
    // map<int,userContext> Map;
    // Map[1] = a;
    cout << a.value1 << endl;
    cout << a.value2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But If I introduce a map, it gives an error. Why is it so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class userContext {
public:
    int id;
    int value1;
    int value2;
    userContext():id(-1),value1(-1),value2(-1){}
    userContext(userContext &context) {
        this->id = context.id;
        this->value1 = context.value1;
        this->value2 = context.value2;
    }
};
int main() {
    userContext a;
    a.id = 1;
    a.value1 = 2;
    a.value2 = 3;
    map<int,userContext> Map;
    Map[1] = a;
    cout << Map[1].value1 << endl;
    cout << Map[1].value2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

part of compilation error output:

```
locks.cpp:20:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:292:17: error: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = userContext]’ declared to take const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
```

However, changing copy constructor signature to `userContext(const userContext &context)` resolves the compilation error and programs executes fine. Please explain.

Thanks!

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` [Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h?lq=1).  Your program is uncompilable on the platform that I would test on.

Comment: In addition, your copy constructor has a flaw in that it fails to copy the `id` member.  So now you have fake copies being generated.

Comment: Your question is sort of a duplicate of [Why C++ copy constructor must use const object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956693/why-c-copy-constructor-must-use-const-object), but the answer to your question would be to remove your copy constructor implementation and let the compiler generate the default one for you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , yes corrected !

Comment: @DanielLangr my comment didn't bring anything that was not already said, hence removed, but still standard copy constructor would be const&.

Comment: @Debashish _Please explain._ This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43607151/580083.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Agree, but it would be good to explain why `std::map` requires its mapped type to require such a _standard copy constructor_ (edit: Bathsheba just did it in his answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A copy constructor that does not pass the copied object by `const` reference does not satisfy the requirements of an *AllocatorAwareContainer* which is one of the *concepts* requried by a `std::map`.

In the absence of your passing in an alternative *allocator* on the `std::map` construction, compilation will fail.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer

Comment: Thanks !. one QS. If I put a `cout <<"hello"<<endl;` statement at the start of the copy constructor, then why is it not getting printed? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Debashish Maybe the copy constructor is not being called.  Compilers are allowed to elide the copy constructor.

Comment: now it's confusing. the map needs the `const` argument in user-defined copy constructor and it did not even call it.

Comment: The code needs to be syntactically correct.  Optimizing the code is a different issue *after* the compiler deems your code as being correct.